# Special use cases for the figure element in HTML5

Tags: html

Please let me know if my understanding of the figure element is accurate.

To the best of my knowledge, the figure element seems to have two types of children, the object in question (img, table, video, quotes, etc) and the description of that object.  Because only a single figcaption can exist within the figure, any and all content describing it must be included inside.  If you want to straddle the figure with text, that would need to be done with CSS.

[image: Example of a figure with heading and caption]

In the example above, the markup would be:

```html
<figure>
  <img src="#" alt="placeholder">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>Exhibit 1.1: Example of Something</h2>
    <p>Lorem...</p>
    <p>Ipsum...</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

```css
figure {
  padding: 60px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}
figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
}

figcaption h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

This feels clunky to me.  Are my assumptions about the figure wrong?  Is it acceptable to mark it up close to the final appearance so that the heading can reflow and its easier to reason about?  As in:

```
<figure>
  <h2>Exhibit 1.1: Example of Something</h2>
  <img src="#" alt="placeholder">
  <figcaption>
    <p>Lorem...</p>
    <p>Ipsum...</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Syntactically yes, that's valid.

Comment: @j08691 which one?  I'm hoping the second HTML snippet is allowable

Answer (score 3):

Your assessment is spot on. Here are the edited highlights of `figcaption` in action...

1. You can only have one `<figcaption>` element.
2. The `<figcaption>` element is optional.
3. Everything else inside the `<figure>` is treated as being "the figure" that the caption relates to (i.e. it may be multiple images, or a code example etc)
4. If you have a lot of "caption" it should all go into the `<figcaption>` element.

Comment: Would it be explicitly wrong to consider the heading be part of "the figure", or do you think that would be too liberal of an interpretation?

Comment: I would expect the header to be part of the `figcaption` (because the header is actually the most appropriate caption in most cases). I definitely think `Exhibit 1.1: Example of Something` sounds like a caption :) - I can see that this will cause you some layout pain.

Comment: Layout pain is an understatement.  Between verbose external content developers and the need for responsive design, it will be impossible to avoid line breaks.